# How to pass same browser instance across different class in selenium framework

Tags: java, selenium

I have a basic doubt on selenium framework on which I am working currently.
I have a driver class where the chrome-driver is initialized.

```
 public class page1 {

            private static  WebDriver driver;
            protected static String WINDOWS_DRIVER = "/chromedriver/windows/chromedriver.exe";
            public static WebDriver initi(){
            if(driver == null){
                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",page1.class.getResource(WINDOWS_DRIVER).getFile());
                DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
                ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
                options.addArguments("test-type");
                options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
                options.addArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");
                capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
                driver=new ChromeDriver(capabilities);

        }

        return driver;
    }
}
```

I have 2 classes which extends the driver class.

```
    public class page2 extends page1 {
    public WebDriver driver;

    public void testmethod1(){
        driver=super.initi();
        driver.navigate().to("https://www.google.co.in/");
    }
}

    public class page3 extends page1 {

    public WebDriver driver;
    public void testmethod2(){
        driver=super.initi();
        driver.navigate().to("https://in.yahoo.com/?p=us");
    }
}
```

Finally, I have a testsuite class where I want to create a single browser instance and call methods of all 3 classes.

```
    public class finalclass extends page1{

    public page2 _page2;
    public page3 _page3;

    public WebDriver driver;

    @Test
    public void finaltest(){

        driver=super.initi();
        driver.get("http://www.rediff.com/");
        _page2.testmethod1();
        _page3.testmethod2();

    }
}
```

It is throwing null pointer exception error on the function call. Can you please help.

Comment: Please show your work. Like this the problem is so vague.

Comment: Hi @Saifur, Thanks for your comments. I have added the code sample. Can you please have a look and let me know!

Comment: You need to include the stacktrace of the Exception to show where things are going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Create a constructor in `page1` class and instantiate the driver there.
- Do not instantiate the driver in every class after inheriting. Instead use the inherited one.

See an example [here](https://github.com/safrrhmn/SeleniumTestNG/tree/master/src/main/java/com/github/pageobjects)

Comment: Thanks for the details Saifur! I have implemented the details as per your advice but still getting null pointer exception for function call in final class in `_page2.testMethod1()`

Comment: Possibly the way you are instantiating the driver is not correct. I would suggest you to pull down my repository and step into to see how that works.

Comment: Seems like I am instantiating correctly as the first `driver.get()` is working fine. But the function call after that, its unable to pass the driver instance.

Comment: Do you use the constructor from super? Or using default constructor? Default constructor will not pass the driver instance correctly

Comment: It worked now after declaring the driver static. Thanks a lot for your time and help.